# Update audit database name in triggers and views of main database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, trigger

I have a a system with two databases, main database and audit database. A lot of the triggers and table views in the main database and audit database are referencing from one database to the other. No I needed to change both databases names but unfortunately they failed to work because they still have the old names in the code.

Is there a code to search and replace the old name used for referencing or in dependence?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You can use the text column from `sys.all_sql_modules` to create alter scripts with your new database names. Below is an example where I use AdventureWorks2014 to replace any text where there is a `CREATE` with an `ALTER` while changing database name `HumanResources` to `HR`.  Again this will only generate your scripts.

EDIT: Replaced `syscomments` with `all_sql_modules`.  Thanks Kenneth Fisher!

```
USE AdventureWorks2014
GO

SELECT 
    o.name,
    o.type,
    o.type_desc,
    sc.definition,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(sc.definition, 'CREATE ', 'ALTER '),'[HumanResources]','[HR]')
FROM sys.all_sql_modules sc
    inner join sys.objects o 
        on sc.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE o.type IN ('V','TF','P','TR') --Views, Table Function, Proc, Trigger. You can include/exclude additional types if you choose.
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it was by 
generating script > select tables only > in the advance options change triggers to True and everything else to False > Generate the script to new query > Find all **CREATE TABLE** code and delete them > Find **CREATE TRIGGER** and replace it with **ALTER TRIGGER** > Find old Database name and replace it with new databse name > then run the code.

This should update all triggers with the new database name as a reference.